# Laravel mail bcc

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

I am using the default Laravel `Mail` class to send emails.

I am trying to add bcc to myself, but when I add a bcc the email is not send at all.
Here is my code:

```
Mail::send(
    'emails.order.order',
    array(
        'dateTime'  => $dateTime,
        'items'     => $items
    ),
    function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName) {
        $message->from('my@email.com', 'My Company');

        $message->to($toEmail, $toName);
        $message->bcc('mybcc@email.com');

        $message->subject('New order');
    }
);
```

Comment: I think that `bcc` required an array `$message->bcc(['mybcc@email.com']);`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have found the problem.
I didn't use the correct parameters for `$message->bcc('mybcc@email.com');`

I had to write email AND name: `$message->bcc('mybcc@email.com', 'My Name');`
The same way as I use `$message->to($toEmail, $toName);`

Comment: That was helpful, absolutely not obvious that it's not sending without a name.

Answer (score 3):

As Ivan Dokov said, you need to pass the email and name to the bcc function.
You could also shorten your code by doing this

```
  function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName) {
        $message->from('my@email.com', 'My Company')
                ->to($toEmail, $toName)
                ->bcc('mybcc@email.com','My bcc Name')
                ->subject('New order');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved just adding the 'bcc' after 'to', without name, just with email address.

```
->to($email)
->bcc($other_email)
->send(new YourMailHere);
```