# How can I add a BCC to my code

Tags: php, bcc

```
Mail::send(['html' => 'emailtemplate'], $dataCustomer, function ($m) use ($input)
{

$m->from('quotes@email.net', 'Mr. Foot');

$m->to($_POST['email'])->subject('Mr Foot Thanks You');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional headers for the Bcc field.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

See [this related Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525415/php-email-sending-bcc).

---

Edit: Looks like you are using the Laravel framework. To add a bcc, you can call:

```
$m->bcc('address@domain.com', 'Name');
```

Here's the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail).

Comment: You should post the actual code necessary to make it work instead of a bunch of links.

Comment: I know that I can add them in the headers but on this page there are no headers to be seen.

Comment: Hi Ed - sorry I wasn't super clear. See my edit.

Comment: ok added $m->bcc('address@domain.com', 'Name');
below the $m>to
didnt send to the addess I added

Comment: That's too bad. It looks like this person had good luck using that method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774204/laravel-mail-bcc

Comment: got it to work I had a space at the end of the $m->bcc('address@domain.com', 'Name')